# How to add the same value to all cells within a dataframe column (pandas in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have an EXCEL table that I want to transfer into a dataframe matching our project's standard with 22 different columns. The original EXCEL table, however, only has 13 columns, so I am trying to add the missing ones to the dataframe I have read from the file.

However, this has caused several challenges:

1. When assigning an empty list `[]` to the dataframe, I get the notification that the size of the added columns does not match the original dataframe, which has circa 9000 rows.
2. When assigning `np.nan` to the dataframe, creating the joint dataframe with all required columns works perfectly:

`f_unique.loc[:, "additional_info"] = np.nan`

But having `np.nan` in my data causes issues later in my script when I flatten the cell data as all other cells contain lists.

So I have tried to replace `np.nan` by a list containing the string "n/a":

`grouped_df = grouped_df.replace(np.nan, ["n/a"])`

However, this gives me the following error:

`TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'float'`

Is there a way in which I can assign 9000 x ["n/a"] to each new column in my dataframe directly?
That would most likely solve the issue.

Comment: wy don't you just [`reindex`]() with the lis of wanted columns? `df.reindex(columns=list_of_cols)`?

Comment: I tried that, but it only gave me the original 13 columns. But good to know it OUGHT to work.

Comment: Better provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), there might be a tiny detail that we could spot easily ;)

Comment: @OnceUponATime - Seems need `df.reindex(df.columns.union(new_cols, sort=False), axis=1, fill_value=["n/a"])`

Comment: I found the issue! I was using the same df dataframe name after reindexing, but when assigning a new variable, it worked! ```df2 = f_unique.reindex(columns=column_names, fill_value="n/a")```

Comment: @OnceUponATime it shouldn't have been an issue, using a new name should map to the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) and for new columns use for filling list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(3)})

new_cols = ['additional_info','new']

df = df.reindex(df.columns.union(new_cols, sort=False), axis=1, fill_value=[])
print (df)
   a additional_info new
0  0              []  []
1  1              []  []
2  2              []  []
```

---

```
df = df.reindex(df.columns.union(new_cols, sort=False), axis=1, fill_value=["n/a"])
print (df)
   a additional_info    new
0  0           [n/a]  [n/a]
1  1           [n/a]  [n/a]
2  2           [n/a]  [n/a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
out = df.reindex(columns=list_of_cols)
```

If you want a list as default value (which you should really avoid):

```
out = df.reindex(columns=list_of_cols, fill_value=['n/a'])
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, reindexing (see answers) above in combination with assigning the same list multiple times to a dataframe column worked best for my use case:

```
df2 = f_unique.reindex(columns=column_names, fill_value="n/a")

# populate some of the empty columns with data

df2.loc[:, "event_end"] = df2["event_start"]
df2.loc[:, "event_type"] = ["Funktionsausübung"] * 31414
```

Adding a list multiple times is certainly not the most elegant solution, but it did the trick.